# laravel, как передать экземпляр класса в свой метод?

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите как передать класс в метод, с другими аргументами?
Допустим если перезаписываю базовый метод модели

```
store($id)
```

, и добавляю туда еще один аргумент:

```
store($id, OrderService $orderService)
```

все работает и я могу работать с сервисом внутри метода, но если создаю метод сам, допустим в классе ProductService:

```
someMethod($id, OrderService $orderService)
```

и при вызове функции с определенным ид, получаю ошибку о недостаточности аргументов, как решить эту проблему не создавая новый класс? как это работает при методе store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно понять, что лара внедряет зависимости только там, где автоматически создает объекты. В случае методов контроллеров это работает, но в случае, если ты сам создаешь класс, или вызываешь метод, тебе надо вручную передавать требуемы аргументы.

Если ты свой сервис внедряешь при помощи контейнера, то используй внедрение зависимостей через `__construct(OrderService $orderService)`, но если тебе нужно получить инстанс требуемого сервиса только в методе, можешь использовать

```
$orderService = app(OrderService::class);
```